# I need to screw into my wall but halfway in, it hits something hard

Tags: walls, screws, hanging

I tried in different spots on the wall but same thing. Is the whole wall like that? I live in a concrete building but not soundproof. I am able to use screws on other walls.

Comment: your probably hitting concrete or brick. Im not sure since I can't see it.

Comment: There's no way we could tell what your wall is constructed of without more info. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes a concrete wall will not have full-depth studs on it.  Instead it will have thin (sometimes only 3/4") firing strips attached to the concrete and the wallboard or paneling gets attached to those strips.  If you are using long screws, chances are good that you are just hitting the concrete.

One way to test this would be to drill a small hole where there *is not* a stud and probe the wall with the bit to see how deep it is.  If the wall is shallow and you have thin firing strips, hanging heavy objects on the wall can be a challenge because you will have to use special anchors and partially drill into the concrete or brick.  You have to know a little more about how the wall is built to know that drilling the concrete will be safe.

Answer (score 3):

### Generally, hitting a hard thing means STOP

There's a convention that says you can safely use 1-1/2" nails or screws without having to worry about nicking an electrical wire, water or sewer line.  **Where one of those comes within 1-5/8" of the finished wall surface, there is supposed to be a metal plate guarding it**. Precisely to warn hole-drillers like yourself that pressing further will damage utilities.

There may be construction types that create this effect unnecessarily, but you should stop unless you have data to support that.  Nailing a water supply pipe is not something you want to do!